# Render Visual 3D Container on top in Viewport3D

Tags: wpf, 3d, viewport3d

Using Helixtoolkit you have set up a scene (viewport). Added the camera, default lights, grids, etc. You also added a SortingVisual3D where you add various box elements for example. They are rendered as they are placed in the view. Everything fine.

Now I would like to achieve is to create a new container for 3D objects where my moving gizmo would be placed (every object gets one). If I add gizmo to sorting container, it might not be visible (box overlapping gizmo), so I need a separate container which **has to be** rendered on top of everything.

How to set container (content) to be rendered on top of everything - regardless of its physical location while still keeping it in the correct 3d space when rotating camera. Something like [3dsmax does (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRugP.png).

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution myself. What you want to do is to make an overlay and transform Point3D to Point and place objects there (a canvas for example).